# Nil Value encountered when unwrapping optional in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, web-services

I am nw to Swift programming and am trying to display JSON objects in an iOS application, but keep receiving the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when running the code.

Here is the code to display the JSON:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class EventList
{
    static var listOfEvents = [Event]()

    static var eventService:EventService?

    static func getEventsFromWebService()->[Event]
        // _ siteURL:String, _ searchTerm:String    
    {
        let searchURL = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?
        date=2018&app_key=wjwMpjZWRD7JXHPQ"
        print ("Web Service call = \(searchURL)")

        eventService = EventService(searchURL)

        let operationQ = OperationQueue()

        operationQ.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        operationQ.addOperation(eventService!)

        operationQ.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()


        listOfEvents.removeAll()

        let returnedJSON = eventService!.jsonFromResponse
        let JSONObjects = returnedJSON?["event"] as! [[String:String]]

        for eachJSONObject in JSONObjects
        {
            print("Creating Movie object from JSON: \(eachJSONObject)")
            listOfEvents.append(Event(eachJSONObject))
        }

        return listOfEvents
    }

    private static func showCreatedList()
    {
        for evt in listOfEvents
        {
            print(evt.displayEvent())
        }

    }
}

class Event
{
    private (set)var title:String
    private (set)var city_name:String
    private (set)var country_name:String
    private (set)var venue_name:String
    private (set)var venue_address:String
    private (set)var start_time:String
    private (set)var url:String
    private (set)var isSaved:Bool

    init?(_ t:String, _ ci:String, _ co:String, _ vn:String, _ va:String, _ 
s:String, _ u:String)
    {
        if ((t == "") || (va == "") || (s == ""))
        {
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            title = t
            city_name = ci
            country_name = co
            venue_name = vn
            venue_address = va
            start_time = s
            url = u
            isSaved = false
        }
    }

    convenience init(_ JSONObject:[String:String])
    {
        let title = JSONObject["title"]
        let city = JSONObject["city_name"]
        let country = JSONObject["country_name"]
        let venue = JSONObject["venue_name"]
        let address = JSONObject["venue_address"]
        let time = JSONObject["start_time"]
        let url = JSONObject["url"]

        self.init(title!,city!,country!,venue!,address!,time!,url!)!
    }

    func displayEvent()->String
    {
        let strEvent = "\(title) will take place at \(venue_name)"
        return strEvent
    }
}

class EventService:Operation
{
    var urlReceived: URL?

    var jsonFromResponse: [String:Any]?

    init(_ incomingURLString:String)
    {
        urlReceived = URL(string: 
incomingURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: 
CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
    }

    override func main()
    {
        var responseData:Data?

        do
        {
            responseData = try Data(contentsOf: urlReceived!)
            print("Service call (request) successful! Returned: \
(responseData)")
        }
        catch
        {
             print("Service call (request) failed")
        }

        do
        {
            jsonFromResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
responseData!,options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
            print("JSON Parser successful. Returned: \(jsonFromResponse!)")
        }
        catch
        {
            print("JSON Parser failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is part of the JSON I am using:

```
{
"last_item": null,
"total_items": "3983377",
"first_item": null,
"page_number": "1",
"page_size": "10",
"page_items": null,
"search_time": "0.129",
"page_count": "398338",
"events": {
  "event": [
    {
      "watching_count": null,
      "olson_path": "America/New_York",
      "calendar_count": null,
      "comment_count": null,
      "region_abbr": "VA",
      "postal_code": "23229",
      "going_count": null,
      "all_day": "0",
      "latitude": "37.5949",
      "groups": null,
      "url": "http://richmond.eventful.com/events/lettermen-/E0-001-
102252139-0?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic",
      "id": "E0-001-102252139-0",
```

The JSON continues on showing different event objects. 
The error is being flagged on the line:

```
let JSONObjects = returnedJSON?["event"] as! [[String:String]]
```

I am working with people who have used similar code but a different set of JSON data, so I am not sure if it is my JSON data or my code that is the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try `let JSONObjects = returnedJSON?["event"] as? [String:Any]`

Comment: @D.Desai Tried that, I get the same error but on the line `for eachJSONObject in JSONObjects!` instead

Comment: print JSONObjects do u get anything or its just nil

Comment: Don't use `!`. your telling the compiler 'this value will not be nil' but it is!. Your JSON cannot be cast to `[[String: String]]` because some values are null. try `[[String: Any]]` or `[[String: String?]]`

Comment: The JSONObjects appear in the output console, followed by the error code. The simulator will also crash.

Comment: @Scriptable XCode won't allow me to do that. It throws up an error saying `'Any?' is not convertible to '[[String:Any]]'` and says I have to use `as!` Same thing when I try `[[String:String?]]`

Comment: Xcode is just a code editor. You don't *have to* do anything it suggests. Sometimes the fix suggested by Xcode is worse than the error. What you have to do is to understand why this error appears, and to properly refactor your code in order to fix it. Do *not* use `!`.

Comment: Aside from the keys `event` and `url` the JSON is not related to the properties in the `Event` class at all.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see at first glance it seems that you have null values on your JSON, but when initializing the class Event you're saying that all fields are mandatory.

```
self.init(title!,city!,country!,venue!,address!,time!,url!)!
```

These are all mandatory fields and from what I can see your JSON only has the url field the translation from JSON to your class will reproduce an error unless you initialize the class by yourself